# How to allow cross origin on iframe through sandbox parameter

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, sandbox, iframe-app

App is render as 'iframe' micro app and there is another 'iframe' within microapp 'iframe'.

Micro app iframe renders as below:

`sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups allow-modals allow-forms allowdownloads allow-same-origin"`

when inner iframe try to access outer iframe then it creates below error:

`Blocked a frame with other` "https://microapp-ifram.com" from accessing a cross origin frame.`

Is there any way on "sandbox" parameter which can allow cross origin ?

By removing "sandbox" it worked but having "sandbox" causes CORS issue.
I can not remove "sandbox" as its not in control. but, I can add any additional attribute to fix CORS.

Something like this if any valid sandbox parameter:
`sandbox="allow-scripts allow-popups allow-modals allow-forms allowdownloads allow-same-origin <ALLOW CROSS ORIGIN> "`

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/441757. You need to use postMessage. There is no alternative.

Comment: @sideshowbarker actually, I am using blob URL child iframe to parent iframe like `printJS(URL.createObjectURL(file))`  // here, printJS executed on child iframe and containing parent iframe blob URL. And causing an issue, Is there a way to `postMessage`  for `printJS(URL)` ?